# Formatting Google API Call - Create/Insert User to Domain, error: Login Required

Tags: curl, google-api

I'm trying to add new users to my google apps account domain ([link1](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#create_user) [link2](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert)) using curl terminal calls via the google api.

I already have an access and refresh token, and just need to figure out how to make the api call.  This is what I've been testing:

```
//version 1
curl https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token_here}" \
-d '{"name":{"familyName":"pan","givenName":"peter"},"password":"asdf","primaryEmail":"asdf@dsf.com"}' \
-X POST

//version 2
curl https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?fields=name%2Cpassword%2CprimaryEmail&key={api_key_for_browsers}
-H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token_here}" \
-d '{"name":{"familyName":"pan","givenName":"peter"},"password":"asdf","primaryEmail":"asdf@dsf.com"}' \
-X POST
```

but they just return the error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

even though the access key I have originates from the authorization code provided after the user logs in and grants access to my app.

My questions:

1. Why do I receive the "Login Required" error even though I've already had the user log in?
2. What is the correct way to format this query?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm getting the same issues.